# unique identifier in a dataset, index problems

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

My question is about Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn& TensorFlow book,
there's a text that says:

> If you use the row index as a unique identifier, you need to make sure that new data
>   gets appended to the end of the dataset, and no row ever gets deleted.

I don't understand why deleting a row could cause problems,
if i delete a row of the data, and then split the data using hashlib to get the training-set and test-set, the test-set is the same, without the row removed obviously,the test-set hasn't been altered,indexes don't change,
so what is the problem about deleting rows and adding row(not in the end of the data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a general tip/ good practice.
1. Where you put the row has big importance if you split by index (like first 80% index and next 20%) or if you are doing a time series project.
2. If you think you are appending rows, but you are overwriting them, you might be losing data without realizing it.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand it will cause problems if I'm going to delete a row though

Comment: can you be more specific? or ask a new question?

Comment: Sorry about that. So, like I don't understand why it is a good practice to not delete any rows in my data set if I'm using row based indexing. Let's say I delete the last row, and it might cause the size of test/training set to decrease in size by one but if I update my data set (by loading it in my code) and recreating the test and training set, why would it cause any difference?

Comment: I think you misread it. The bad practice is using row based indexing because it can add or REPLACE (hence delete) old rows. It is just a dangerous way of working. I mean, imagine if I car worked like that. You press gas, but sometimes it goes backwards. Would it feel safe?

Comment: I can see the problems with using row based indexing (example if the data set changes orders or items are inserted anywhere but at the end). "he bad practice is using row based indexing because it can add or REPLACE (hence delete) old rows", could you clarify this with an example if possible? Is that not supposed to happen? Like are we supposed to create a train, test set and never modify it or something. Sorry for so many ambiguous questions, I have just started learning ML

Comment: This is an example ```python
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]})
df.loc[3] = 5
print(len(df))

df.loc[3] = 9
print(len(df))


```

If you cant see what is going wrong here, it means you are not ready to understand it and you can avoid worrying about it for the moment :))) Or you can just open a new question!

Comment: Thanks for the example. I can see that the data "5" is getting lost, because we are overwriting it, not sure if this is the right answer. I suppose you're right, I will open a new question about this topic

Comment: that's correct, well seen!